# How to install older versions using Homebrew

Tags: homebrew

I'm trying to install memcached with older versions (ex: 1.4.5) but I'm not sure how to do it.

`brew install memcached` installs the latest.

I also tried `brew install memecached1.4.5` but it didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Homebrew install specific version of formula?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula)

Comment: Answer covered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula

Comment: Answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula not worky for me, this one does

Answer (score 164):

Usually, you can check if multiple versions are available and you can specify the version with @. e.g. brew install package@2.8

```
$ brew info memcached

memcached: stable 1.4.24
High performance, distributed memory object caching system
https://memcached.org/
Conflicts with:
  mysql-cluster (because both install `bin/memcached`)
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/memcached.rb
...
```

If is not available the version you want you can go to the repo, and check the history

```
cd "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)"
git log master -- Formula/memcached.rb
```

Then you can find the commit you are looking for

```
commit 5ec463decefeaab3d1825b923ad2dbee73ffc6dc
Author: Adam Vandenberg <flangy@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Apr 9 21:19:48 2010 -0700

    Update memcached to 1.4.5
```

Checkout that version and install:

```
cd "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" && git checkout 5ec463decefeaab3d1825b923ad2dbee73ffc6dc
HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 brew install memcached
```

Once you get the version installed:

```sh
git checkout master  # bring brew back to its latest version
brew pin memcached   # [optional] prevent formula from updating
```

and, that's it!

Comment: If you already have it installed, you might need to do `HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 brew upgrade memcached` instead.

Comment: This works but I feel like this process should be much easier. Installing older versions isn't that uncommon of a use case

Comment: To view the full log, you might have to run `git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow` since brew has a shallow clone of the repository by default.

Comment: Also, `brew pin memcached` will keep it from being upgraded automatically in the future.

Comment: Thank you so much for this - this was a lifesaver.
fwiw this is a hilariously rediculous workaround for the most basic usage of a package manager

Comment: `brew tap --force homebrew/core` may be required on the current version of homebrew before `cd "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)"`. Then `brew untap homebrew/core` as the last step to clean up.

Answer (score 12):

This works in 2019

```bash
brew unlink memecached
brew install memecached@1.4.5
brew link memecached@1.4.5 --force
```

Comment: ==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.

Comment: @Madeo what is the name of the formulae you're trying to install? Maybe you need to tap that first (Tapping means adding their external repository into brew)

Answer (score 4):

2021 update:

```sh
$ curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/<commit-hash>/Casks/<FORMULA>.rb > $(find $(brew --repository) -name <FORMULA>.rb)
$ brew reinstall <FORMULA>
```

You can find the cask or formula file URL here and the commit message should describe the file version to grab the URL for.

```
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commits/master/Formula/<formula>.rb
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/commits/master/Casks/<cask>.rb
```

Credit: https://remarkablemark.org/blog/2017/02/03/install-brew-package-version/

Comment: A few field notes here: The first `curl` in the first snippet is indeed a `cask`, modify to `formula` if needed using the second snippet. Also, you don't have to copy the entirety of the commit `hash`, 7 `char`s suffice.

Answer (score 2):

A more expanded version of the good answer from Adrian is also here on SO.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53766019/3794873

One thing to keep in mind is that if you are installing an older Formula the Homebrew API/methods may have changed since that time so you should `brew edit appFormula` against the current version and compare to the `brew edit app@your.version` if you encounter any errors trying to `brew install app@your.version` after the `brew extract` command in the answer linked.

Answer (score 2):

If the version you are looking for was already **deleted** from the Homebrew repository:

1. Find the formula in the Homebrew repo. For example, I needed [solr](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/solr.rb).
2. Go to the file History and find the version you need. For example, I needed [solr 8.11.2](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/8400730997ae589261783a1973896d2c3cdd6791/Formula/solr.rb).
3. Get the Raw link to the file and get it locally. For my case:

   ```
   curl -o /tmp/solr.rb https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/8400730997ae589261783a1973896d2c3cdd6791/Formula/solr.rb
   ```
4. Install the formula but make sure the autoupdate is turned off. For my case:

   ```
   HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 brew install --formula /tmp/solr.rb
   ```
5. Pin the formula so that it is not updated by accident. For my case:

   ```
   brew pin solr
   ```
6. Follow homebrew instructions as usual.

Answer (score 1):

Sharing an interactive oneliner I made for myself of [Adrian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/684957/adrian)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187812/homebrew-how-to-install-older-versions/46306176#46306176) now:

It does a simple parsing, depending only on "/blob/" in the github URL, of "From" in `brew info`, and does a bash `select` of commit from `git log`.

`brew install` can be replaced with `brew reinstall` as needed.

Tested (for cask "name=powershell") in `bash` **5.1** (from macports ;P) and `env -i /bin/bash` **3.2** on *macOS (High Sierra) **10.13.6*** against `brew` **3.3.11**. (I might have done some tap'ing the other day.)

`(name= && { [[ $name ]]||read -ep "Name: " name;} && [[ $(brew info "$name"|sed -Ene'/^From: (.*)/s//\1/p') =~ ([^/]*)/blob/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*) ]] && V=("${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1}") && N=(repo current dir file) && for s in ${!N[@]};do eval "${N[s]}=\${V[s]}" && declare -p >&2 "${N[s]}";done && cd "$(brew --repo "${repo//-//}")" && IFSO="$IFS" && IFS=$'\n' && select line in $(git log --oneline master -- "$dir/$file");do IFS="$IFSO" && commit=($line) && break;done && set -x && git checkout "$commit" && HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 brew install "$name" && git checkout master)`

Skål, salud, cheers!